# Parallel.For is very slow when I am trying to call HTTPWebRequest function

Tags: parallel.for

In this method, I am trying to loop through DataSet.Table which has approx. 65K records only , however, the loop is taking for every or it fails with Aggregate exception.

Can somebody please point me what am I doing wrong?

```
        Parallel.For(0, dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count,  row =>
        {
            try
            {

                var downloadedValue = Helper.GetResponse(<<WebRequestMethod>>)");
                if (downloadedValue != null)
                {
                    actualTable.Rows.Add(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[row]["Id"].ToString(), dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[row]["LastModifiedDate"].ToString());
                }

            }
            catch(AggregateException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            }
        });
```

Comment: You should put in some timing but I expect our problem is adding to the dataset concurrently.  You can look at this for some ideas: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188748.aspx

Comment: You're making making 65,000 web requests? I would expect that to take quite a while. Supposing 4 web requests per second, this would take 4 hours to complete.